# Prettifying exception handling in function

Tags: java, exception

Can this func. not be prettified?
Can the the catch clause be left empty, I have heard it's frowned up on.

`apiClient.accountList()` is where the exception can occur.

```
public Optional<Account> getAccount(String accountUuid) throws ApiException {
    try {
        for (Account account : apiClient.accountList()) {
            if (account.getUuid().equals(accountUuid)) {
                return Optional.of(account);
            }
        }
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Comment: Why are you saying that `getAccount()` throws an `ApiException` when you already catch that exception inside the function?

Comment: @Turamarth see edit to the question please!

Comment: @NathanHughes yes that is the intention, just to return `Optional.empty()` but to have to have it duplicated does not please the eye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Stream, assuming `getUuid` does not throw an `ApiException`.

```
public Optional<Account> getAccount(String accountUuid) throws ApiException {
    try {
        return apiClient.accountList().stream()
            .filter(account -> account.getUuid().equals(accountUuid))
            .findAny();
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        /* Log exception */
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Actually instead of collection returning methods like `accountList()` it more and more makes sense to use Streams, `accountStream()`.

Comment: As there is no `@Override` the last clean-up would be to remove `throws ApiException` (if indeed you want that catch).

Answer (score 2):

If you're very motivated to avoid the duplicate return statement, a simple tweak to the control-flow should do it. As mentioned in the comments, logging exceptions is often a good idea.

```
public Optional<Account> getAccount(String accountUuid) throws ApiException {
    Optional<Account> result = Optional.empty();
    try {
        for (Account account : apiClient.accountList()) {
            if (account.getUuid().equals(accountUuid)) {
                result = Optional.of(account);
                break;
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (ApiException e) { /* Log exception */ }
    return result;
}
```